# Автоматический запуск скрипта без функции старт и апдейт

Tags: unity3d

У меня вопрос, можно ли в unity автоматически запустить часть скрипта (по подобию Button/On Click)?
Функция старт или апдейт не подходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Описание малость сумбурно. Опишите что именно Вы хотите получить, какие вводные данные и условия?

Comment: У меня есть скрипт, в нем есть функция которую я вызываю через кнопку. Можно ли вызвать эту функцию другим способом или что бы эта функция вызывалась автоматически

Comment: лично я не понял ни вопроса ни уточнения в коментарии. Пожалуста, хорошо обдумай вопрос и переформулируй максимально понятно что хочешь получить в результате

Comment: Функции Start и Awake именно для этого и созданы - что бы вызыватся автоматически при создании обьекта (эвейк немного раньше старта). Если же хочется в другой момент вызывать - можно воспользоватся ивентами или екшнами. Но по-факту, по вопросу похоже что ты хочешь сделать какую-то дичь и тебя нужно от этого уберечь. Что бы уберечь -- нам нужен правильно заданный вопрос.

Comment: (добавил код) Я вызываю функцию load через кнопку, но хочу чтобы функция load вызывалась автоматически на сцене

Comment: а start или awake по идее не подходит

Comment: Хотя нет через Start работает (когда в первый раз побывал выдавал ошибку)

Comment: А это точно серьезный вопрос или автору было лень самому разобраться? Вы даже не потрудились отдебажить код перед тем, как задать вопрос.

Comment: Я проверял (я же написал что в юнити по какой то причине выводило ошибку, я подумал что это надо по другому делать по этому я и написал сюда)

Comment: @shifu, прочитайте ещё раз правила форума и прокникнитесь. Не стоит начинать вопрос с проблемы, которая у вас возникла при решении вашей проблемы. Начинайте с самого начала - "я попытался сделать вот это и у меня оно выдало вот такую ошибку, я теперь пытаюсь сделать вот так, но тоже не выходит". При подобной формулировке вопроса гораздо проще будет вам помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае достаточно вызвать метод load() в нужный момент. 
Это значит, что где то в вашей программе должна быть строчка 
    myVariableOfSaveLoadSceneType.load();

Нужный момент знаете только вы. Например, вы набрали 100 очков, и тогда должна срабатывать загрузка уровня.

```
if(score==100)
{
   myVariableOfSaveLoadSceneType.load();
}
```

Или зашли в коллайдер, стоящий на конце уровня, а на нем код:

```
OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
   myVariableOfSaveLoadSceneType.load();
}
```

И тому подобное. Ещё могу посоветовать методы типа вашего load() делать статическими. Или пользоваться шаблоном ["одиночка"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPKAgyp8cno).  Это избавит от необходимости делать переменную класса SaveLoadScene где то выше по коду. В видео по ссылке как раз подгрузка уровня разбирается.